# Выключение и включение звоночка и проблема с cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

Нужно сделать что-то типо звоночка для системы.

Сделал, но если выключаешь его, то выключается в рамках страницы, а не в рамках всего поддомена, как поправить или что не так написал?

код такой

```
if (getCookie('soundjob') == 0) {
    $('.control-sound').addClass('off'); 
} 
if (getCookie('soundjob') == 1) {
    $('.control-sound').addClass('on');
}

$('.control-sound').click(function(){ 
if($(this).hasClass("on")) { 
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off'); 
    cetcooke('0'); 
} else { 
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on'); 
    cetcooke('1'); 
} 
});

function soundClick() {
    if (getCookie('soundjob') == '1') {
      var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
      audio.src = 'http://account.u-crm.ru/js/n3.mp3'; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
      audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
    }
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
                        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
                    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : false;
}

function cetcooke(status) {
    var date = new Date;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15); // время жизни куки
    document.cookie = "soundjob="+ status +"; expires="+date.toUTCString()+"; path='/'"; // ставим куку 
}
```